# SDL + OpenGL: access violation when creating buffer

Tags: c++, opengl, buffer, sdl, glew

I'm trying to make a window using SDL and then draw to it using GLEW and OpenGL.

so far I've made a window and initialized it with OpenGL, but when I try to create a buffer I get a wired exception.

My code looks like this:

```
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    SDL_Window* window;
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    //creating SDL window
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("",100,100,500,400,SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

    //setting up opengl
    SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    glClearColor(0.6f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    //check if glew was initialized properly
    if (glewInit() == GLEW_OK)
        std::cout << "glew ok" << std::endl;
    else
        goto end;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////I'm Getting The Error Here
    GLuint bufferID;////////////////////////////////
    glCreateBuffers(1,&bufferID);///////////////////
    glDeleteBuffers(1,&bufferID);///////////////////

    SDL_Event sdlEvent;

    //event loop
    while (1)
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&sdlEvent))
            if (sdlEvent.type == SDL_QUIT)
                goto end;

    end:
        SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

error: `Exception thrown at 0x00000000 in opengl_project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000.`

Comment: [`glCreateBuffers()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glCreateBuffers.xhtml) is only in GL 4.5, are you actually getting a GL 4.5 context?

Comment: Uhm, I'm not sure how can i check? Is it my opengl dll file thats outdated? Or is it glew?

Comment: [`glGetString(GL_VERSION)`](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetString.xml) after your `glewInit()`.  Or [check if `GLEW_VERSION_4_5` evaluates to true](http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html).

Comment: i just tried and i get version 4.3. So i am using an outdated version but is it glew or opengl thats outdated? because i dont know where i can get another opengl32.dll

Comment: also, if its outdated then how are other programs on my computer, that use opengl, still working?

Comment: Reported OpenGL version is regulated by your GPU and GPU driver.  Upgrade either to (potentially) get a new OpenGL version.  Are those other working OpenGL programs using GL 4.5-only features?

Comment: so i tried updating my graphics driver but it said it was already up to date, but i guess thats just because nvidia doesn't support opengl 4.5+ yet? but now im kind of in a pickle because im trying to follow an opengl tutorial on youtube and he's using buffers quite a lot and i'm not familier with any other ways of drawing using opengl.. but i guess that's my own problem i'll have to figure out on my own. thanks alot :P

Comment: @vats: nvidia supports OpenGL 4.5, but only with graphics cards which can provide this support. Apparently your graphics card is too old and no driver updates will fix that. With older OpenGL versions you can use `glGenBuffers` and then bind them with appropriate functions instead of `glCreateBuffers`. Which card and driver version do you have?

Comment: alright thanks ill use glGenBuffers then, and i have a geforce 920m

Comment: oh i just looekd it up on their website and it says that the geforce 920m supports opengl 4.5....thats so wired, ill try redownloading the driver or something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that opengl was outdated (version 4.3) and glCreateBuffers is a 4.5+ feature

If you have a simular problem a solution could be updating your graphics driver or just using glGenBuffers (version 1.5+) instead.